Fetch details from 2 tables using typeorm
I have 2 table MainBranch and Subbranch
get the details from both the tables based on branch code
and branchname
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
export class MainBranch {
   
    @Column()
    branchcode: string

    @Column()
    branchName: string

    @Column()
    branchContact: string
    
    @OneToOne(() => SubBranch, SubData => SubBranch.branchcode)
    @JoinColumn({branchcode})
    SubData:SubBranch

   
}



 import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm"
    
    @Entity()
    export class SubBranch {
       
        @Column()
        branchcode: string
    
        @Column()
        subName: string
    
        @Column()
        subContact: string

         @OneToOne(() => MainBranch , MainBrnachData => MainBranch.branchcode)
        MainBrnachData :MainBranch 
          
    }

I tried the below  querys  for that. But it throws an error "Query failed unknown column "
const details = this.mainBranchRepository.find(
                 relation:{
                    SubData:true,
                   },
                  where:{branchcode,branchname}
                 )
console.log(details )


You are missing the @JoinColumn() decorator in the MainBranch entity which is required and must be set only on one side of the relation, otherwise no foreign key is created between the two tables.

@Entity()
export class MainBranch {
   
    @Column()
    branchcode: string

    @Column()
    branchName: string

    @Column()
    branchContact: string
    
    @OneToOne(() => SubBranch, SubData => SubBranch.branchcode)
    @JoinColumn()
    SubData:SubBranch

   
}

